# PYGAME как сделать зону в которую нужно кликать

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Я пишу игру на Pygame и
мне нужно что бы когда я направлял курсор в область, например (150 px, 150 px), в области от 0,0 пикселей до 150,150 пикселей в консоль что-нибудь выводилось.

```
import pygame as pg 
pg.init()

SIZE = (800, 600)

sc = pg.display.set_mode(SIZE)

FPS = 30
clock = pg.time.Clock()

while True:
    sc.fill('BLACK')
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            pg.quit()
            quit()
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION: 
            print(1)
            

    pg.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: Код в студию пжлста

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так будет лучше :-)

```
import pygame as pg
from pygame import gfxdraw

pg.init()

SIZE = (800, 600)

sc = pg.display.set_mode(SIZE)

FPS = 300
clock = pg.time.Clock()

sc.fill('BLACK')

while True:

    pg.draw.rect(sc, color=(255, 0, 0), rect=(0, 0, 150, 150), width=2)
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            pg.quit()
            quit()
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION:
            position = pg.mouse.get_pos()
            x, y = position

            if x < 151 and y < 151:
                print(f"Координаты курсора: {x}, {y}")
                gfxdraw.pixel(sc, x-1, y-1, (0, 255, 0))
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            position = pg.mouse.get_pos()
            x, y = position

            if x < 151 and y < 151:
                #print(f"Координаты курсора: {x}, {y}")
                print("Событие: клик мышью")
                gfxdraw.pixel(sc, x, y, (255, 255, 255))
                gfxdraw.pixel(sc, x-1, y, (255, 255, 255))
                gfxdraw.pixel(sc, x, y-1, (255, 255, 255))
                gfxdraw.pixel(sc, x+1, y, (255, 255, 255))
                gfxdraw.pixel(sc, x, y+1, (255, 255, 255))
    pg.display.update()
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: спасибо помог!!

Comment: если будет не трудно переделать код, я просил что бы в эту зону надо было нажать а не просто навестись!!

Comment: Сам тоже немного думай

Answer (score 0):

Все конечно работает, но когда я в строке где есть range пытаюсь поменять значение.

```
living_surface = [(x, y) for x, y in zip(range(100), range(100))]
```

не range(100), а на range(50, 100).
оно перестает работать!

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите